# This is not a text file(zend optimizer)

Tags: php, zend-framework, encoding, binary, zend-optimizer

```
<?php @Zend;
4123;
/* !This is not a text file!

print <<<EOM

//here goes some zend html code for information

exit();
__halt_compiler();

//here goes the binary data, instead of php code
```

I have downloaded a file to view/edit from the hosting, and I see this....many php files are corrupted with binary data, so I can't edit it and I don't know how can this be fixed, or how can I decode this binary data?

Comment: its zenguard encoded, you don't edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you have opened is a binary and not a text file.

That is why there is no source-code.

You get the source-code by contacting the original author of that file.

Btw, the file is not corrupted. It is just not human read- and editable.

See as well: [Decode a PHP encoded with 'zend guard'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298001/decode-a-php-encoded-with-zend-guard)

Comment: so the only way is contacting the developer who has encoded this file yes?