# Migrating zend encrypted website between servers

Tags: php, zend-guard, kohana-2

I've been given the task of moving a zend encrypted website (the previous owners fell out with their developers and now they don't have the decrypted version).

It's based on the php framework Kohana, (which unfortuantely i've never used)

I've done all the webserver setup, right version of zend optimizer etc but I can't get past this error:

> An error was detected which prevented the loading of this page. If
>   this problem persists, please contact the website administrator.
>   /LINK/system/core/Kohana.php [199]: Kohana::setup(): Filename cannot
>   be empty Loaded in 0.0587 seconds, using 1.22MB of memory. Generated
>   by vsCommerce v3.3.10

I can't look in Kohana.php as it's encrypted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode a PHP encoded with 'zend guard'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298001/decode-a-php-encoded-with-zend-guard)

Comment: Note to responders: This project appears to be using Kohana 2.x because `Kohana::setup()` is a function only present in that version.